# Calling class method, when changing tab

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabbar

I have the following tab navigation structure:

tab1: Sound Player Screen (where you can play sounds),

tab2: Info Screen,

tab3: Settings Screen,

I want that the sound player stops playing (the class has stop() method) , when I switch from Sound Player tab to info or settings tab. I've tried to use tabBarOnPress, but I don't really understand how to call the stop method from there. I've tried stuff like this :

```
static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarOnPress: ({previousScene,scene,jumpToIndex}) => {
        previousScene.stop();
        jumpToIndex(scene.index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is surprisingly difficult to achieve using `react-navigation`, because it turns out to be quite tricky to know which screen currently has focus with the current state of the library (see long issue [here](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/51)).

One solution is to use [react-navigation-is-focused-hoc](https://github.com/patlux/react-navigation-is-focused-hoc), which wraps your screen component providing a boolean in props which you can check. Given that, you can put something like the following in the `componentWillUpdate` of your `tab1`:

```
componentWillUpdate (nextProps) {
  if (!nextProps.isFocused) {
    // component is going out of focus, stop the music
    this.stop()
  }
}
```

Note: I recommend using the version of the library I linked, it's Patrick Wozniak's fork which is slightly more up to date.